# What's the best way to save an ActiveRecord model instance?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I am still new to Ruby on Rails and in my models I often do this:

```
def activate
  update_column(:activated, true)
  update_column(:activated_at, Time.zone.now)    
  update_column(:activation_token, nil)
end
```

What difference does it make if I instead do this?

```
def activate
  self.activated = true
  self.activated_at = Time.zone.now
  self.activation_token = nil
  save!(:validate => false)  
end
```

I still don't unterstand the difference between these two approaches. Which one is *faster* or more efficient from a database point of view?

Comment: Skipping validations often means your validations are wrong.

Comment: But what is wrong in this case if I simply want to `activate` a new user without having to validate his name, password etc. all over again? That would be such a pain...

Comment: Why would it be a pain? It happens automatically… If your concern is the performance of validations, it’s unlikely to be relevant.

Comment: OK, you are probably right. But if I just use `save!`, I get get this error: `Validation failed: Password is too short (minimum is 6 characters)`. How can I skip this?

Comment: Have a valid password? Or make password validation conditional based on some criteria.

Comment: You mean a validation method like `validates :password, :on => [:create, :update]`? Is that safe?

Comment: If you don’t want it to be at least six characters, then remove or change the validation on password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `update_column` as soon as the call is made, a query is generated and executed on the database. So you end up with three update queries.

But when you change the `object`'s attributes using the second method, and then finally call `save`, a single query will be generated and executed to make all the changes made on the `object` (representing the record).

So in terms of effeciency you should always go with the second one. Remember the lesser the number of writes or queries on the database the better!

Comment: Thanks, that explains it very well I think.

Answer (score 1):

#### update_column :

Updates a single attribute of an object, without calling save.

- Validation is skipped.
- Callbacks are skipped.
- updated_at/updated_on column is not updated if that column is available.
- will fire 1 query for each update_column call.

where as

#### save :

- will perform validations, callbacks, update updated_at column and will fire a single query.

For your case second option is definitely the better one and yes, you should remove `:validate => false` form save to avoid any validation issues.